# Limit of a Recursive Sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm having a really hard time finding the limit of a recursive sequence -

$$ \begin{align*}
&a(1)=2,\\
&a(2)=5,\\
&a(n+2)=\frac12 \cdot \big(a(n)+a(n+1)\big).
\end{align*}$$

I proved that the sequence is made up from a monotonically increasing sequence and a monotonically decreasing sequence, and I proved that the limits of the difference of these sequences is zero, so by Cantor's Lemma the above sequence does converge. I manually found out that it converges to $4$, but I can't seem to find any way to prove it.

Any help would be much appreciated! 
Thank you.

Comment: related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468385/solving-recurrence-equation-using-generating-function-method

Comment: Look at $a(n)-4$; you should be able to (experimentally) find a simple equation for these values, and once you have such an equation it's easy to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

It never hurts to look at some data. Calculate the first few terms:

$$2,5,\frac72,\frac{17}4,\frac{31}8,\frac{65}{16},\frac{127}{32}$$

We can even fit the first two numbers into the apparent pattern:

$$\frac1{1/2},\frac51,\frac72,\frac{17}4,\frac{31}8,\frac{65}{16},\frac{127}{32}$$

The denominator of $a(n)$ appears to be $2^{n-2}$, and the numerators are alternately one less and one more than a power of $2$. Specifically, it appears that the numerator of $a(n)$ is $2^n-1$ when $n$ is odd and $2^n+1$ when $n$ is even or, more simply, $2^n+(-1)^n$. We conjecture, therefore, that

$$a(n)=\frac{2^n+(-1)^n}{2^{n-2}}\;.$$

Now prove this by induction on $n$, and observe that it’s now trivial to calculate the limit of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

We can write the general term as 
$$\tag1 a(n) = u+\left(-\frac12\right)^n\cdot v$$
(because $1$ and $-\frac12$ are the two solutions of $x^2=\frac12(x+1)$).
From $a(1)=2=u-\frac12 v$ and $a(2)=5=u+\frac14 v$, we find $u=v=4$.
From (1) it is clear that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a(n)=u=4$$

Answer (score 1):

First, given $\mathbf{a}_i=[a_i,a_{i+1}]^T$, you can express the sequence as $\mathbf{a}_{i+1}=M\mathbf{a}_i$. Find the infinite power of $M$ by diagonalizing it and raising the diagonal term to an infinite power. Then the limit is $M^\infty\mathbf{a}_0$.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine someone who is unable to answer the question on his own but who can understand and use this answer.  So far, my imagination has not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

giving a little elaboration to [Hagen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen)'s answer: note that what we have here is a linear recurrence relation and assume a solution of the form $a(n)=x^n$. Observe:$$a(n+2)=\frac12(a(n)+a(n+1))\\x^{n+2}=\frac12(x^n+x^{n+1})\\x^{n+2}-\frac12x^{n+1}-\frac12x^n=0\\x^n\left(x^2-\frac12x-\frac12\right)=0$$... which yields the trivial solution $x=0$ but also the solutions $x=1,-1/2$, i.e. $a(n)=1$ and $a(n)=(-1/2)^n$ are two solutions to the above recurrence.

Because our problem is linear it follows any linear combination of $1,(-1/2)^n$ satisfies our equation, giving the general solution $a(n)=u+v(-1/2)^n$.

Imposing our initial conditions $a(1)=2,a(2)=5$ we determine our coefficients $u=v=4$ giving the solution $a(n)=4+4(-1/2)^n$. Clearly $a(n)\to4$ in the limit as $n\to\infty$.